# Is there a way to use column A to autofill column B

Tags: google-sheets

I use Sheets to inventory unique items I stock in my online store, and how much they weigh. I'm looking to be able to write in the name of an item, and if an exact match exists somewhere else in the sheet, to autofill the weight in the column next to it. For example I would start with the table:

| Name | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | 1.2 |
| Product B | 0.5 |
| Product C | 2.2 |
|  |  |

And then input another, for example, Product A into the Name column, and the weight 1.2 is automatically filled in as I hit enter:

| Name | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | 1.2 |
| Product B | 0.5 |
| Product C | 2.2 |
| Product A | **1.2** |

As an aside, I do it this way rather than quantifying how many of each item I have, i.e. Product A having a Stock value of 2 stored together, as it helps to know roughly when I stock something chronologically. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

use `VLOOKUP`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, C:D, 2, 0)))
```

where C:D is your first table and A2:A is 1st column of your 2nd table

Comment: I may be wrong, but my impression is that poster wants to be able to type products and their weights into, say, ColA and ColB; then, if they type a product further down in ColA that has already been typed somewhere above that in ColA, ColB would detect this and autofill the corresponding cell in B, ad infinitum. That is, I don't the poster understands the concept that the reference chart would need to be separate from the entry chart.